# MySql If statements

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a simple table that logs simple events an administrator does.  Nothing complicated.

One of the columns is `userid`, so I can reference the user's name from the users table:

```
SELECT u.username FROM `users` u, `history` h WHERE u.userid = h.userid
```

My issue is that the internal system also logs events (just like a user), but there is no userid related to the internal system.  It is simply logged as zero, in the record.

Is there a way to modify the query to reflect this?  I've tried a LEFT JOIN, but that doesn't let me specify "system" as the username.  The other thing i can do is enter a new user into the user's table, and call it "Internal System".  But I really don't want to do that.

Is it possible to do this from the query level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT COALESCE(u.username, 'SYSTEM') AS username,
     FROM HISTORY h
LEFT JOIN USERS u ON u.userid = h.userid
```

`COALESCE` will return the first non-NULL value, so if you LEFT JOIN onto USERS and `username` is NULL--then "system" or whatever you prefer will appear.